# Using salt-cloud with oVirt

Tags: virtual-machine, salt-stack, salt-cloud, ovirt

I have a small cloud, configured and set up with SaltStack. The instances are running on Xen right now.

I would like to use oVirt instead, with automatic provisioning of virtual machines (via salt-cloud, I guess).

Apparently, there is no formula for this yet. Also, one cannot just use virsh on the command line or something (oVirt uses its own XML files for configuration and has virsh disabled). There is a REST API for oVirt, but I would prefer something already made before I dive into this and try to make it work with salt.

I have searched for oVirt and salt, but have found almost nothing.

Can I use oVirt with salt-cloud to do automatic provisioning? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be an `oVirt` salt cloud driver yet. Here's the list of currently supported clouds:

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/cloud/#cloud-provider-specifics

Comment: We are using saltstack 2016.x version.. all our minions are having the same version. what our problem is, states in the top file wasn't executed in order. we can't put order: x inside each state and also can't use require:xx.sls in each state.. I know there is an option for salt states to work in the order (`state_auto_order`) defined in top.sls but it's for the 17.x version.. is there any way to tell salt to execute in the order defined in top.sls ?

Comment: Salt will execute jobs in order.  The minion evaluates the top file from top to bottom, collects which sls files it should execute, then executes them in order. `requires` will change the order.    Do you have an example of this not working?

Comment: yep.. My `top.sls` file looks like https://pastebin.com/1sNx3Mvy . Everytime I run a highstate using `salt -G 'roles:*' state.apply`,  it shuffles the order . One time, my console logs shows `bar` summary at first and for the next time it shows `buzz` summary at very first.. I think internally, the states work in order. But I want the `foo` states to get executed first then `bar` and then `buzz`